# Decentralized PLC Network using Soft-PLC

Tags: plc, codesys

My setup is a tracked mobile robot which needs to be controlled using a PLC. For numerous reasons, it is necessary to have a decentralized computing unit (e.g. located in the office) which sends the commands to the tracked robot. The computing unit runs on a industrial Soft-PLC (in our case "CODESYS Control WIN"). The basic idea is, that the decentralized unit does the heavy computing and the local unit is just a proxy (i.e. "Read Sensor Data and send it to decentralized unit" as well as "Get Controls from decentralized unit and send commands to ECUs")

Question is: How is it possible to do this kind of decentralized setup, i.e. How to route commands from local Codesys instance to decentralized unit?

[image: Sketch of Workflow]

Comment: Can't you just define command variables to send over the bus, and have the local controllel perform the said command on the rising edge of that command variable?

Comment: I would use mqtt..check the codesys website, there should be a library there..

Comment: If you use Codesys 3.5 you can use NVL (Network Variable List), it is very simple to use and it is possible to pass a complex list of parameters (BOOL, REAL, INT, LREAL...). Another more complex option is to use UDP/TCP blocks, which also works in Codeys 2.3. Look for the OSCAT library.